# Prerequisites for AI and machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, education

I am interested in the field of AI and machine learning and I am fairly good at mathematics and statistics and programming in general. However I lack a formal CS education and my undergraduate degree was in an unrelated field.

What are the typical prerequisites for a master's-level course in AI and machine learning?

Comment: I don't think compiler theory is important if you're doing machine learning. If you're doing natural language processing, the basics could be marginally useful.

Comment: I don't see why compiler theory is the elephant in the room. What about automata theory? Formal language theory? Discrete mathematics? Theory X, for some value of X?

Comment: Compiler "theory", or more generally compiler courses, is often an
opportunity to learn programming paradigms, structures and concepts,
and get some perpective of what they entail and what facilities they
give. Compiler technology is a good way of understanding programming
languages and techniques. There are probably other ways to learn that,
and it does not entail understanding everything in compiler
technology. But there is more to it than just being good at
programming. I am old and would recommend the Abelson-Sussman book
(available on the web), but there are others.

Comment: @DaveClarke is right, compiler theory is not the elephant in the room: it is a dragon.

Comment: I don't think this question is particularly opinion-based, so I disagree with the close vote. For example, everybody seems to agree that compiler theory is largely irrelevant to AI. Since that's been dealt with, I've edited the question to be more generally applicable and more clearly factual.

Comment: (By the way, since the asker probably isn't familiar with it, the point of @babou's comment is that the most well-known book on compiler theory is Aho, Sethi and Ullman's _Compilers: Principles, Techniques, & Tools_, known as "the dragon book" because of its front cover. Apologies to everyone else for ruining the joke by explaining it.)

Comment: It is unfortunate that there are not more discussions on curriculum
issues, just to understands pros and cons for including specific
topics. For example, I keep wondering why students do so much syntax
analysis technology, as opposed to general principles. Or why some
classical result is still taught in original form, though that form is
obsolete.

Comment: We lack a proper close reason for "career advice"-type questions, but it's nonetheless not an SE-good question. I recommend moving the discussion to [chat].